# comparing elements with generics types in java

Tags: java

below is the given code .
At function SelectionSort i have used compareTo() function but its not working..

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.Comparator;
   import java.util.Random;
   public class Sorting8 {
   public static void main(String[] args){


    Scanner k=new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r=new Random();
    System.out.println("1.Integer Sorting Testing");
   System.out.println("2.Character Sorting Testing");
   int choice=k.nextInt();

   switch(choice)
   {
      case 1:
        Integer[] a={44,33,11,55,77,90,40,60,99,22,88,66};

        SelectionSort(a,a.length);
        break;
    case 2:
   Character[] a1= {'D','A','T','A','S','T','R','U','C','T','U','R','E'};
        SelectionSort(a1,a1.length);
        break;
   default:
    System.out.println("Wrong choice");
  }


  }

public static <T> void SelectionSort(T[] a,int n) 
{

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        T x=a[i];
        int j=i-1;
    //HERE i have used the compareTo() function but not working properly                 
        while((j>-1) && ( (a[j].compareTo(x)<0))
        {
            a[j+1]=a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1]=x;
        }
       }
    }
```

//here the selection sort is done using the by providing the inputs should have     generic type

Comment: Just use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])).

Comment: but by using that function we can sort it in a particular pattern but if we want to sort it in other pattern and having a control over each element if we want to print or not

Comment: If you want to sort using another pattern, call [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) with a custom `Comparator`. No need to implementing the sorting yourself, just the comparison logic.

Comment: can u give me a example of using Array.sort()

Comment: Sure: http://www.google.com/q=arrays.sort+example+java

Comment: but it only compares the String but i want to compare any data type variable

Comment: What only compares the string? You can write any type of `Comparator` you want.